# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent mixing similar column names

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.2, PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.7.

So, I have a table with two columns with similar names: `prp_preco_terceirizador` and `prp_preco_terceirizador2`.

This is the Model file for that table:

```
class ProdutoPreco extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'produto_preco';
    protected $primaryKey = 'produto_preco_id';
    public static $eagerLoadClass = [];

    const CREATED_AT = 'cadastrado';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'atualizado';
    const DELETED_AT = 'excluido';

    public function produtoVariacao()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProdutoVariacao');
    }

    public function getPrpPrecoTerceirizadorAttribute($value)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $cliente = Auth::user()->userable()->first();
            if ($cliente->cli_desconto_maximo == 'S' && 
                (!is_null($this->prp_preco_terceirizador2))) {
                return $this->prp_preco_terceirizador2;
            }
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function getPrpCodPrecoTerceirizadorAttribute($value)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $cliente = Auth::user()->userable()->first();
            if ($cliente->cli_desconto_maximo == 'S' &&
                (!is_null($this->prp_cod_preco_terceirizador2))) {
                return $this->prp_cod_preco_terceirizador2;
            }
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Table structure for produto_preco:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `produto_preco`;
CREATE TABLE `produto_preco`  (
  `produto_preco_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `produto_id` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `produto_variacao_id` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `prp_qtd` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `prp_preco` decimal(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `prp_cod_preco` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `prp_preco_terceirizador` decimal(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `prp_cod_preco_terceirizador` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `prp_preco_terceirizador2` decimal(10, 2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `prp_cod_preco_terceirizador2` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `excluido` datetime(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cadastrado` timestamp(0) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `atualizado` timestamp(0) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),
  `prp_preco_OLD` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`produto_preco_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `idx_1`(`excluido`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `idx_2`(`excluido`, `produto_variacao_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 8592 CHARACTER SET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

Everything works fine, but, when I run this:

`$aux = ProdutoPreco::find(123)`

If I dump the returned object the values are correct, but both these lines return me the value of `prp_preco_terceirizador2`:

`$aux->prp_preco_terceirizador2`

`$aux->prp_preco_terceirizador`

I changed `prp_preco_terceirizador2` to `prp_preco_terceirizador_max`, and the print_r showed the correct values, but the individual object properties still returned the same value. Only when I changed `prp_preco_terceirizador` to `prp_preco_terceirizador_min` the values were returned correctly.

Does someone have an explanation for that?

Comment: You are talking about `prp_preco_terceirizador` and `prp_preco_terceirizador2`, but your code contains frequent usages of `prp_cod_preco_terceirizador` and `prp_preco_terceirizador_max`. A bit of background would be helpful...

Comment: Oh, sorry, this is the altered code. This prp_cod_preco_terceirizador isn't used at all. The prp_preco_terceirizador_max references are the old prp_preco_terceirizador2, I'm editing now.

Comment: Well, currently it's quite obvious to me why you receive the same result for both attributes. Due to your custom accessor `getPrpPrecoTerceirizadorAttribute()` which returns `prp_preco_terceirizador2`, this is the logic behavior...